# Is URL with multiple neighboring / duplicate

Tags: url, duplicates, seo, webserver

I have two url

```
http://foo.bar/example
```

and

```
http://foo.bar///////example
```

Web servers execute the second URL the same as the first. Is the second URL valid? Do search crawlers understand it as duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

If your server render it as `http://foo.bar///////example`, it means its a duplicate content.

But as you say, if the web server execute the second URL same as first, crawler not going to read as a duplicate content.

Even so best solution is using the [cannonical](https://moz.com/learn/seo/canonicalization).